# SPARQL query insert ObjectProperty is not working

Tags: java, spring-boot, sparql, jena, fuseki

I am trying to insert in TDB through Fuseki server. it does add DataProperty but it doesn't add the objectProperty and I can't figure out what's the reason.

**OWL File example:**

```
    <owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/hightech/ontologies/2019/8/untitled-ontology-4#BCA">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/hightech/ontologies/2019/8/untitled-ontology-4#Concept"/>
        <before rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/hightech/ontologies/2019/8/untitled-ontology-4#CA"/>
        <part_of rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/hightech/ontologies/2019/8/untitled-ontology-4#ADT"/>
        <depth_level rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">1</depth_level>
        <description rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"></description>
        <id rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">BCA</id>
        <name rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">Basic Concept of ADT</name>
    </owl:NamedIndividual>
```

**Java Code:**

```
        String queryString =
                    "PREFIX ns:<http://www.semanticweb.org/hightech/ontologies/2019/unit#>"
                    + "PREFIX rdf:<http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>" 
                    + "INSERT DATA{" 
                    + "<http://www.semanticweb.org/hightech/ontologies/2019/unit#" + conceptcostmizeCode + "> ns:name \""+ newConcept.getName() + "\";" 
                    + "ns:id \"" + conceptcostmizeCode + "\";" 
                    + "rdf:type ns:Concept;" 
                    + "ns:description \""+ newConcept.getDescription() + "\";" 
                    + "ns:depth_level \"" + newConcept.getDepth() + "\";"
                    + "ns:part_of \"" + newConcept.getPart_of() + "\";"
                    + "ns:belongs_to \"" + newConcept.getOntologID() + "\";" 
                    + "ns:require \""+ newConcept.getRequire() + "\"." + "}";

    UpdateRequest request = UpdateFactory.create(queryString);
            UpdateProcessor qe = UpdateExecutionFactory.createRemote(request,
                    "http://localhost:3030/myDataSet/update");
            qe.execute();
```

Comment: I don't get it, what exactly is missing? And that you have to put URIs in angle brackets, i.e. `<some_proper_uri>` is clear to you? Currently you put everything in between quotes like `"some_string"`

Comment: the ObjectProperty(like part_of, belongs_to, require in the question) is missing although I am adding it in my insert query. and I used quotes to write my query in String format then pass it to the execution. I edited the code

Comment: you are escaping the quotes which means they become quotes in the query string - this is wrong. I already told you that using quotes means the value is a literal ... what you have in your query is `<http://www.semanticweb.org/hightech/ontologies/2019/unit#123> ns:part_of "http://some.uri/example"` - if the value is a literal then the property is a data property. What you have to do is to use the prefixed URI or the URI wrapped in angle brackets: `<http://www.semanticweb.org/hightech/ontologies/2019/unit#123> ns:part_of <http://some.uri/example>`

Comment: @UninformedUser thank you, I didn't notice that (copy-paste typing error) but still doesn't solve my problem. could it be the Fuseki reasoner?